# How to get 'process name' of appllications, if it is different from 'package name'?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Here is my scenario,

Suppose I have package name of some application, and presently I’m finding whether the application is running by passing the "packagename" to following method

```
boolean isNamedProcessRunning(String packageName){
             if (packageName == null) 
              return false;

             ActivityManager manager = 
                (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
             List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
             for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes)
             {
                  Log.e("", "----> processname "+process.processName);

                 if (packageName.equals(process.processName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
             }
             return false;
            }
```

I know, by default android takes the package name as the process name. But if  process property in application tag is defined in manifest file android:process="com.example.newprocessname" then the application will run with this name "com.example.newprocessname".

How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
boolean isNamedProcessRunning(String packageName){
    if (packageName == null) 
     return false;

    ActivityManager manager = 
       (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < process.pkgList.length; i++){
         Log.e("", "----> pkg name "+ i + process.pkgList[i]);
         if(process.pkgList[i].equals(packageName))
             return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
String arr[] = process.pkgList;
```

then compare the package name with arr items. It will give all packages that have been loaded into the process(As per doc).